# Can I run oc commands in openshift pod terminals?

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

Is there any way that I can run the oc commands on pod terminals? What I am trying to do is let the user login using

```
oc login
```

Then run the command to get the token.

```
oc whoami -t
```

And then use that token to call the REST APIs of openshift. This way works on local environment but on openshift, there are some permission issues as I guess openshift doesn't give the root permissions to the user. it says permission denied.

**EDIT**

So basically i want to be able to get that BEARER token I can send in the HEADERS of the REST APIs to create pods, services, routes etc. And i want that token before any pod is made because i am going to use that token to create pods. It might sound silly I know but that's what I want to know if it is possible, the way we do it using command line using oc commands, is it possible on openshift.

The other possible way could be to call an API that gives me a token and then use that token in other API calls.

@gshipley It does sound like a chiken egg problem to me. But if i were to explain you what I do on my local machine, all i would want is to replicate that on openshift if it is possible. I run the oc commands on nodejs, oc.exe file is there in my repository. I run oc login and oc whoami -t. I read the token i get and store it. Then I send that token as BEARER  in API headers. Thats what works on my local machine. I just want to replicate this scenario on openshift. Is it possible?

Comment: Discussion about this happening at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openshift/LQZqbbrCWU0

Answer (score 2):

As a cluster admin create new `Role` as e.g. role.yml

```
apiVersion: authorization.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: mysudoer
rules:
  apiGroups: [''],
  resources: ['users']
  verbs: ['impersonate']
  resourceNames: ["<your user name>"]
```

and run

```
oc create -f role.yml
```

or instead of creating raw `role.yml` file, use:

```
oc create clusterrole mysudoer --verb impersonate --resource users --resource-name "<your user name>"
```

then give your ServiceAccount the new role

```
oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user mysudoer system:serviceaccount:<project>:default
```

download the `oc` tool into your container. Now whenever you execute a command you need to add `--as=<user name>`, or to hide that, create a shell alias inside your container

```
alias oc="oc --as=<user name>"
```

the `oc` should now behave exactly as on your machine, including the exact same privileges as the `ServiceAccount` only functions as an entry point to the API, but the real tasks are done as your user.

---

In case you want something simpler, just add the proper permissions to your `ServiceAccount`, e.g.

```
oc policy add-role-to-user admin -z default --namespace=<your project>
```

if you run the command, any container in your project that has `oc` will be able to auto-magically do tasks inside the project. However, this way, the permissions are not inherited from the user as in the first step, so it's always required to manually add them to the service account as needed.

---

Explanation, there is always `ServiceAccount` in your project called `default`. It has no privileges a thus can not do anything, however all necessary credentials for authenticating the `ServiceAccount` are by default in every single container. The cool thing is that `oc`, if you do not provide any credentials, and just run it inside a container in `OpenShift`, it will automatically try to login using this account. The steps above simply show, how to get the proper permissions to the account, so that the `oc` can use it to do something meaningful.

---

In case you simply want access the RESt API, use the token provided in

```
/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

and set up the permissions for the `ServiceAccount` as described above. With that, you will not even need the `oc` command line tool.

Comment: I get the following error while creating role in console.
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "role.yml": User "<username>" cannot create clusterroles at the cluster scope

Comment: As i mentioned above, you need to be "cluster admin" to be allowed to do that. To make that happen you need to run `oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin <username>` and as user with cluster admin privileges (when using minishift do `oc login -u system:admin` to get that privileges). If you can not get that permission (e.g. production cluster), you will need to go with the 2nd approach without impersonation or ask your admins to do that for you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for builder containers too? I'm trying to run `oc` from an S2I assemble script but it doesn't automatically pick up any authentication info from the context (I can manually provide tokens and that will work, but that's of course not what we want)

Comment: when i try this, i get "error: default cluster has no server defined". I had to specify --server=